# Manifold allowing function with two critical points is sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

The only closed manifolds which allow a function with two (maybe degenerate) critical points are spheres. In dimension 2 it is [quite easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930103/a-smooth-function-fs1-times-s1-to-mathbb-r-must-have-more-than-two-critica/971623#971623), but what is about higher dimensions?

Comment: Given Jim's answer below, were you looking for a proof in the topological case, where there is a positive result? That is, every compact smooth manifold which admits exactly two non-degenerate critical points is homeomorphic (not necessarily diffeomorphic) to a sphere?

Comment: *Morse Theory* by John Milnor has a full proof of the topological result mentioned by Grumpy Parsnip.

Comment: @Timkinsella [Milnor mentions](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A9QZZ3S_QxwC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=2+critical+points+homeomorphic+to+a+sphere&source=bl&ots=f2e3Q-MZHp&sig=jA_ogNKtZ2wckc7vQHt7Sw04EJY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g8w7VM71FInTaJ2TgpAF&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=2%20critical%20points%20homeomorphic%20to%20a%20sphere&f=false) that the possibly degenerate case is more difficult than the proof given in *Morse Theory*, but he gives two references for proofs of this more general case.

Comment: @DanielRust Ah, thanks. I should have checked.

Comment: The proof for the non-degernate case is too simple to not mention though. A good example of the power of the Morse lemma.

Comment: @Daniel Rust: Yes, I meant it. Wikipedia link by Grumpy Parnis gives [this article][http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/exotic.pdf], where it is quite easily proven if one of points is non-degenerate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Topologically the answer is yes, but in the smooth category the answer is no. Milnor provided the first examples of topological spheres which are not diffeomorphic to the standard sphere. His argument that they are toplogical spheres uses the fact that there are Morse functions with two critical points. This  [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) should get you started
.